# How do I change class on element when I click a element elsewhere using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I've been looking for a basic example, where when I click a link, a class is added/removed from another element elsewhere on the page?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I would really like to get my head around AngularJS basics.

Thanks

Comment: That's more like JS basics than Angular basics.

Comment: @Shomz Yes I suppose that's true. It's just that I thought it would be a good idea to use Angular seen as it has two way binding as well as wanting to minimise DOM querying.

Comment: Fair enough, let me write you a quick example.

Comment: on ng-click = angular.element('class or id of the element to which u want to add ').addClass()

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that will work within the same controller, and makes use of `ng-click`, `ng-class` and a scope variable `classOn` (generated inline):

```css
.on {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <a ng-click="classOn = !classOn">Click me</a>
  <p ng-class="{on: classOn}">I'm being toggled</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is kind of what I was looking for. Essentially it was for a modal mechanism, where when I click a link, a certain DIV will have the ".modal-in" class added to it, and then when you click the close link in the modal window the DIV with the ".modal-in" class will have another class added to it called ".modal-out". After 1 second when the ".modal-out" CSS animation has finished both classes(.modal-in & .modal-out) will be removed.